# Is it good practice to use ordinal of enum?

Tags: java, enums, coding-style, verbose

I have an enum:

```
public enum Persons {

    CHILD,
    PARENT,
    GRANDPARENT;

}
```

Is there any problem with using `ordinal()` method to check "hierarchy" between enum members? I mean - is there any disadvantages when using it excluding verbosity, when somebody can change accidentally order in future.

Or is it better to do something like that:

```
public enum Persons {

    CHILD(0),
    PARENT(1),
    GRANDPARENT(2);

    private Integer hierarchy;

    private Persons(final Integer hierarchy) {
        this.hierarchy = hierarchy;
    }

    public Integer getHierarchy() {
        return hierarchy;
    }

}
```

Comment: Imo, it depends on  whether you're working with other people and how likely it is that someone would change the enum order later.

Comment: Do you even need a numeric value?  Enum values can be compared with each other directly.  For example, `if (Persons.CHILD.compareTo(Persons.PARENT) < 0) System.out.println("CHILD has a smaller value than PARENT.");`

Comment: `compareTo` in enum is using ordinal to compare

Comment: Code error: `private SourceType` should perhaps be `private Persons`

Comment: @ByeBye, I just updated my answer, adding some more information, please take a look.

Comment: "The ordinal of enum"? That would be enumth.

Comment: People do this sort of thing a lot but it makes code maintenance more difficult.

Comment: Maybe it isn't a job for enum at all.

Comment: @blackcatweb: Would "this sort of thing" mean the first example or the second? Your antecedent is unclear.

Comment: I'm talking about using the ordinal value as an integer.

Comment: There is no reason to use `Integer` objects instead of `int` values here.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

*TLDR: No, you should not!*

If you refer to the javadoc for `ordinal` method in `Enum.java`:

> Most programmers will have no use for this method.  It is
>   designed for use by sophisticated enum-based data structures, such
>   as `java.util.EnumSet` and `java.util.EnumMap`.

Firstly - read the manual (javadoc in this case).

Secondly - don't write brittle code. The enum values may change in future and your second code example is much more *clear* and *maintainable*.

You definitely don't want to create problems for the future if a new enum value is (say) inserted between `PARENT` and `GRANDPARENT`.

Comment: How is having to manually renumber all subsequent items when you insert a new item in the list more maintainable?

Comment: @DavidMoles - good question. Since you are explicitly declaring `hierarchy`, its clear you are associating an `Integer` with each enum. Most importantly, if the enums are somehow re-ordered (say, someone adds `GUARDIAN` on the line between `PARENT` and `GRANDPARENT`) then the value for the last enum value won't change.

Comment: @DavidMoles It may not be the *most* maintainable, but it's clearly better than having your behavior depend on the order in which you happen to have declared your enum values.

Comment: @DavidMoles because the only thing less maintainable is code that will break if anyone changes it in the wrong way, and which adds nothing to explain that fact. Though personally, I would use the first method and adding a comment explaining that order matters...

Comment: @nhouser9 ... and a set of tests that will fail if someone does ignore the comment and changes the order.  If you're in the unfortunate position of having a team where unit tests are not run or failures are frequently ignored and implementation that explicitly numbers them is much safer.

Comment: @ChrisHayes Lots of things depend on the order in which you happen to have declared your enum values, including `compareTo()`, which is `final`. Order is meaningful for Java enums. If you want it not to be meaningful, you should write your own enum-like class with your own ordering rules.

Comment: @vikingsteve If the intent is to allow multiple instances to share the same level, then clearly `ordinal()` wouldn't work in the first place.

Comment: There are many cases where to avoid ordinal, and generally is a maintenance issue due to inherent ambiguity of just "ordinal" within any context. Joshua Bloch in Effective Java discusses this, as well as many academic articles/ papers

Comment: Side note : misuse of ordinal within java is widespread. I agree with above answer

Comment: @vikingsteve Ordinal is a very powerful function. For example if you had a MONTH Enum instance passed to a function which had to print out what # month of the year that month was, the only viable option available would be to use the `ordinal()` function. Calling `values()` is not typically a good practice as it must create an additional copy of the array on every call, which is O(n) space and complexity. Beginners could get the wrong impression from your answer.

Comment: By default, HQL sets enumeration values using the ordinal() method in table columns.

Answer (score 19):

As suggested by Joshua Bloch in *Effective Java*, it's not a good idea to derive a value associated with an enum from its ordinal, because changes to the ordering of the enum values might break the logic you encoded.

The second approach you mention follows exactly what the author proposes, which is storing the value in a separate field.

I would say that the alternative you suggested is definitely better because it is more extendable and maintainable, as you are decoupling the ordering of the enum values and the notion of hierarchy.

Comment: *Effective Java* is probably the best java book ever written

Answer (score 15):

**The first way is not straight understandable** as you have to read the code where the enums are used to understand that the order of the enum matters.
It is very error prone.

```
public enum Persons {

    CHILD,
    PARENT,
    GRANDPARENT;

}
```

**The second way** is better as it is **self explanatory** :

```
CHILD(0),
PARENT(1),
GRANDPARENT(2);

private SourceType(final Integer hierarchy) {
    this.hierarchy = hierarchy;
}
```

---

Of course, orders of the enum values should be consistent with the hierarchical order provided by the enum constructor arguments.

**It introduces a kind of redundancy** as both the enum values and the arguments of the enum constructor conveys the hierarchy of them.
**But why would it be a problem ?**
**Enums are designed to represent constant and not frequently changing values**.
The OP enum usage illustrates well a good enum usage :

```
CHILD, PARENT, GRANDPARENT
```

Enums are not designed to represent values that moves frequently.
 
In this case, using enums is probably not the best choice as it may breaks frequently the client code that uses it and besides it forces to recompile, repackage and redeploy the application at each time an enum value is modified.

Comment: This is a good point but I think it would be just as good to simply add a comment that the order of the identifiers is significant.

Comment: Except the second way really isn't self-explanatory.

Comment: @Robin Davies  you refer to `hierarchy` field name that may be misleading ?

Answer (score 14):

First, you probably don't even need a numeric order value -- that's
what [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)
is for, and `Enum<E>` implements `Comparable<E>`.

If you *do* need a numeric order value for some reason, yes, you should
use `ordinal()`. That's what it's for.

Standard practice for Java `Enums` is to sort by declaration order,
which is why `Enum<E>` implements `Comparable<E>` and why
`Enum.compareTo()` is `final`.

If you add your own non-standard comparison code that doesn't use
`Comparable` and doesn't depend on the declaration order, you're just
going to confuse anyone else who tries to use your code, including
your own future self. No one is going to expect that code to exist;
they're going to expect `Enum` to be `Enum`.

If the custom order doesn't match the declaration order, anyone
looking at the declaration is going to be confused. If it *does*
(happen to, at this moment) match the declaration order, anyone
looking at it is going to come to expect that, and they're going to
get a nasty shock when at some future date it doesn't. (If you write
code (or tests) to *ensure* that the custom order matches the
declaration order, you're just reinforcing how unnecessary it is.)

If you add your own order value, you're creating maintenance headaches
for yourself:

1. you need to make sure your `hierarchy` values are unique
2. if you add a value in the middle, you need to renumber all
   subsequent values

If you're worried someone could change the order accidentally in the
future, write a unit test that checks the order.

In sum, in the immortal words of [Item 47](https://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&lpg=PR11&ots=yZLmRlt6M_&dq=%22item%2047%22%20%22effective%20java%22&pg=PA215#v=onepage&q&f=false):
*know and use the libraries*.

---

P.S. Also, don't use `Integer` when you mean `int`.

Comment: enum fields may be used to other things besides comparison and order.

Comment: @LeonardoPina Yes, but that's not what the OP asked.

Comment: To be fair, it was unclear what OP wanted to do with 'hierarchy'.

Comment: It's not a particularly well-written question, but the only use it explicitly talks about is order, and the example given exactly hard-codes the same values `ordinal()` would give.

Comment: @Davide Moles. Thank you.  A voice of reason in a sea of obnoxious and counterproductive lore . One always struggles with the sort of advice that's been given on this question. I spent two days mulling it over, and eventually came to the same conclusion you did. And was on my way back to write an argument against the use of enum fields in this case, when I found your post. If only I'd noticed it two days ago.

Answer (score 9):

If you only want to create relationships between enum values, you can actually use the trick of using *other enum values*:

```
public enum Person {
  GRANDPARENT(null),
  PARENT(GRANDPARENT),
  CHILD(PARENT);

  private final Person parent;

  private Person(Person parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
  }

  public final Parent getParent() {
    return parent;
  }
}
```

Note that you can only use enum values that were declared lexically before the one you're trying to declare, so this only works if your relationships form an acyclic directed graph (and the order you declare them is a valid topological sort).

Answer (score 7):

Using `ordinal()` is unrecommended as changes in the enum's declaration may impact the ordinal values.

**UPDATE:**

It is worth noting that the enum fields are constants and can have duplicated values, i.e.

```
enum Family {
    OFFSPRING(0),
    PARENT(1),
    GRANDPARENT(2),
    SIBLING(3),
    COUSING(4),
    UNCLE(4),
    AUNT(4);

    private final int hierarchy;

    private Family(int hierarchy) {
        this.hierarchy = hierarchy;
    }

    public int getHierarchy() {
        return hierarchy;
    }
}
```

Depending on what you're planning to do with `hierarchy` this could either be damaging or beneficial.

Furthermore, you could use the enum constants to build your very own `EnumFlags` instead of using `EnumSet`, for example

Answer (score 3):

I would use your second option (using a explicit integer) so the numeric values are assigned by you and not by Java.

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider following example:

We need to order several filters in our Spring Application. This is doable by registering filters via FilterRegistrationBeans:

```
 @Bean
  public FilterRegistrationBean compressingFilterRegistration() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registration.setFilter(compressingFilter());
    registration.setName("CompressingFilter");
    ...
    registration.setOrder(1);
    return registration;
  }
```

Let's assume we have several filters and we need to specify their order (e.g. we want to set as first the filter which add do MDC context the JSID for all loggers)

And here I see the perfect usecase for `ordinal()`. Let's create the enum:

```
   enum FilterRegistrationOrder {
    MDC_FILTER,
    COMPRESSING_FILTER,
    CACHE_CONTROL_FILTER,
    SPRING_SECURITY_FILTER,
    ...
    }
```

Now in registration bean we can use:
`registration.setOrder(MDC_FILTER.ordinal());`

And it works perfectly in our case. If we haven't had an enum to do that we would have had to re-numerate all filters orders by adding 1 to them (or to constants which stores them). When we have enum you only need to add one line in enum in proper place and use ordinal. We don't have to change the code in many places and we have the clear structure of order for all our filters in one place.

In the case like this I think the `ordinal()` method is the best option to achieve the order of filters in clean and maintainable way

Answer (score 2):

You must use your judgement to evaluate which kind of errors would be more severe **in your particular case**. There is no one-size-fits-all answer to this question. Each solution leverages one advantage of the compiler but sacrifices the other.

If your worst nightmare is enums sneakily changing value: use `ENUM(int)`

If your worst nightmare is enum values becoming duplicated or losing contiguousness: use `ordinal`.

Answer (score 1):

According to java [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal%28%29)

> Returns the ordinal of this enumeration constant (its position in its
>   enum declaration, where the initial constant is assigned an ordinal of
>   zero). Most programmers will have no use for this method. It is
>   designed for use by sophisticated enum-based data structures, such as
>   EnumSet and EnumMap.

You can control the ordinal by changing the order of the enum, but you cannot set it explicitly.One workaround is to provide an extra method in your enum for the number you want.

```
enum Mobile {
   Samsung(400), Nokia(250),Motorola(325);

   private final int val;
  private Mobile (int v) { val = v; }
  public int getVal() { return val; }
}
```

In this situation `Samsung.ordinal() = 0`, but `Samsung.getVal() = 400`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to your question. Rather better approach for your usecase. This way makes sure that next developer will explicitly know that values assigned to properties should not be changed.

Create a class with static properites which will simulate your enum:

```
public class Persons {
    final public static int CHILD = 0;
    final public static int PARENT = 1;
    final public static int GRANDPARENT = 2;
}
```

Then use just like enum:

```
Persons.CHILD
```

It will work for most simple use cases. Otherwise you might be missing on options like [valueOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html), [EnumSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html), [EnumMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) or [values()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659217/where-is-the-documentation-for-the-values-method-of-enum).

Comment: The huge downside of that being that arguments for method declarations are of type int, and there is no longer compiler protection against passing an illegal value. This seems like a disproportionate price to pay for avoiding the incredibly subtle downside of using ordinal.

Comment: IMO, that's for enums exist