# How to induce order for Strings and compare against it?

Tags: java, string, collections, comparator

Let's say
`Enum MyClass { ORANGE, APPLE, BANANA; }`

In this case this will be true:
`ORANGE.compareTo(APPLE)<0`
and `Collections.min()` would give me ORANGE

If I have
`private static final String[] values = {ORANGE, APPLE, BANANA};`

Is there a way to return same result.
I tried using `Collections.min(values)`, but the answer was APPLE, because it was using natural order.

I tried using this
`public static <T> T min(Collection<? extends T> coll,Comparator<? super T> comp)` so that it returns the minimum element of the given collection, according to the order induced by the specified comparator.
If I want to have above result, how do I define the Comparator?

Comment: If your array is already sorted then just use `values[0]`? I don't understand what the problem is here.

Comment: I'm only guessing that you want to sort one collection based on an order of some other. If that is the case, check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18129807/in-java-how-do-you-sort-one-list-based-on-another

Comment: What you are actually comparing, whencomparing items of an enum, is not their String value, but their enum ordinal, which is assigned by the order, of the items in the enum.
For an easier way of comparing it you could just get the corresponding ordinal from the enum by calling `MyClass.valueof(someString).ordinal()` and compare that in your comparator.

Comment: @AmirSchnell check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44654291/is-it-good-practice-to-use-ordinal-of-enum). It's not a good practice to use ordinals...