# Is this a correct implementation of Comparator?

Tags: java, comparator

I have a class, Word, that has a String representing a word and an Enum representing the difficulty of the word. Then I have another class, Vocab, that has an ArrayList of Word-objects. I want to sort my ArrayList by either difficulty or by the alphabetical order of the word.

I figured I should use a Comparator, and here is how I did it. All classes are in the same package:

Diff:

```
public enum Diff {
   EASY, MEDIUM, HARD;
}
```

Word:

```
public class Word {
   private String word;
   private Diff diff;

   public Word(String word, Diff diff) {
      this.word = word;
      this.diff = diff;
   }

   public String getWord() {
      return word;
   }

   public void setWord(String word) {
      this.word = word;
   }

   public Diff getDiff() {
      return diff;
   }

   public void setDiff(Diff diff) {
      this.diff = diff;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      String string = getWord() + ", " + getDiff();
      return string;
   }
}
```

Vocab:

```
public class Vocab {
   private ArrayList<Word> words;

   public Vocab() {
      words = new ArrayList<>();
   }

   public void sortByPrio() {
      Collections.sort(words, prioCompare);
   }

   public void sortByName() {
      Collections.sort(words, nameCompare);
   }

   private Comparator<Word> prioCompare = new Comparator<Word>() {
      @Override
      public int compare(Word w1, Word w2) {
         return (w1.getDiff().ordinal() - w2.getDiff().ordinal());
      }
   };

   private Comparator<Word> nameCompare = new Comparator<Word>() {
      @Override
      public int compare(Word w1, Word w2) {
         return (w1.getWord().compareToIgnoreCase(w2.getWord()));
      }
   };

   public void addWord(Word newWord) {
      words.add(newWord);
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      String string = words.toString();
      return string;
   }
}
```

Main:

```
public class Main {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Vocab myWords = new Vocab();
      myWords.addWord(new Word("Apple", Diff.EASY));
      myWords.addWord(new Word("Besmirch", Diff.MEDIUM));
      myWords.addWord(new Word("Pulchritudinous", Diff.HARD));
      myWords.addWord(new Word("Dog", Diff.EASY));

      System.out.println(myWords);
      myWords.sortByPrio();
      System.out.println(myWords);
   }
}
```

Is anything inherently wrong with my code above, regarding my implementation of the Comparator? If so, what should I improve? Also, I haven't redefined `equals`, which I usually do when I implement `Comparable`. Should I redefine it now as well?

Comment: you could use `compareTo()` from the enum class: `return w1.getDiff().compareTo(w2.getDiff());` -- even easier `Comparator<Word> prioCompare = Comparator.comparing(Word::getDiff);`

Comment: ...but other than that seems ok to me :)

Comment: Maybe you should ask on [Core Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Off-topic: Instead of using  `~.ordinal ()`, have the difficulty as field: `public enum Diff { EASY (1), MEDIUM (2), HARD (3); private final level; Diff (int level) { this.level = level; } private int getDifficulty () { return level; }}` See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44654291/is-it-good-practice-to-use-ordinal-of-enum

Comment: And the other one: `public static Comparator<Word> ALPHA_COMPARATOR = Comparator.comparing(Word::getWord, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);`

Comment: The major issues here: [1] equality - no, that's for things that implement Comparable, not for Comparators. [2] It's generally a good idea, if you can, to have a total order. Your difficulty-based comparator doesn't have a total ordering: 2 different items that have the same difficulty would be ordered identically, it's better to then add a secondary order. [3] Use Comparator's many utility methods to do this stuff, such as how g00se's comment shows.

Comment: Your implementation is correct. The suggestions in the other comments are perfectly valid, but they are not saying that the implementation that you already have is directly wrong in any way.

Comment: This really does belong on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Could be much simpler by (a) making `Word` a [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395), and (b) maintaining a pair of lists within `Vocab`, each sorted by either of two static `Comparator` objects [per g00se](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78251998/is-this-a-correct-implementation-of-comparator#comment137956948_78251998) en each addition of a `Word`. In real work, likely to benefit from a plural `addWords` for efficiency. And use clear full words in names, `difficulty` instead of [diff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff).